# Yii2 return javascript through php

Tags: php, yii2

I need to return javascript via php in Yii2 like this:

```
$script_name = "./script.js";
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
if(file_exists($script_name))
{
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($script_name));
    $fp = fopen($script_name, 'r'); 
    fpassthru($fp); 
    exit;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have a ready script that returns script to users (not to guests). And i don't want it will be available for everyone from link like http://mysite/assets/secret_script.js

I want to use Yii, but i dont know hot to do this. If i will use Yii function to add script, it will copy it and add to page like this (but this file doesn't exists, because i use .htaccess   secret.js -> getscript.php). .

If i will use controller the query would be http://site/index.php?r=site/getscript ??

May be it would be php script that use Yii functions ??

I have got a work example, but how to transfer to Yii2 ??

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this to load the script:

```
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl . '/js/script.js', ['depends' => [yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
```

Comment: I need something like $this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl . '/getscript.php') -> result     <script src="/getscript.php"></script>